# How do sites handle long processes that need to happen simultaneously without impacting render calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, web

Background:
I have the game tic tac toe and I have an created an interactive web app to try and teach people the best moves. The AI which works out the best moves is on the front end but it takes a few seconds to run. I want to run the code to 'solve' the game immediately after initially rendering the page but I also want it to stop whenever a user clicks a button etc.  In Java I would simply set up a new thread and put it on there but I understand JS is single threaded? I know this is possible as I have seen it demonstrated in other sites such as https://lichess.org/analysis.  I'm interested in the principle not the solution so please don't suggest things like 'make your AI more efficient' or 'use a hashtable'.

Question:
How do I set a computationally long task running (in the 'background') in React such that the UI elements are not bottlenecked by it?

Comment: You could use web workers for that, those are something similar to threads, there you could move the logic of the AI while the UI thread or "Main thread" keeps responsive. https://web.dev/module-workers/, a very useful library for dealing with workers is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/comlink

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza Thanks very much, I'll look into them

Comment: You can move the heavy processing to a server instead.

Answer (score 0):

> "but I understand JS is single threaded"

JavaScript fully allows for asynchronous programming using promises and asynchronous functions. JavaScript code may be single-threaded in a given context, but other functions such as Fetch API requests executed by the browser are not. This means that you can make an API call to a web server where your AI can take its own sweet time to revert with a response, while your front-end remains responsive to button clicks and so on that can allow the user to cancel operations like you mention.

So to answer your question, one way of achieving what you desire is:

1. Move the "background" work that you mention to a server
2. Use asynchronous programming (promises, async-await) in combination with AJAX/API/Fetch calls to your server to get the results of the background work while your front-end remains responsive.

Please look up asynchronous programming in JavaScript for more.